# PermError SPF Permanent Error: include has trivial recursion

Tags: email, spf

I have configured SPF `v=spf1 include:meetings.xlogix.ca ~all` for the subdomain meetings.xlogix.ca. But SPF verification fails when tried checking from https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

I am getting `PermError SPF Permanent Error: include has trivial recursion` error and mails send to Gmail shows that "Gmail could not verify that it actually came from meetings.xlogix.ca." warning.

How to fix the recursion error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `include:meetings.xlogix.ca` part from your SPF record; it's trying to include itself, hence the "trivial recursion" error.